# Visual Studio Code - .NET Core Test Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, testing, plugins, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run tests through .NET Core Test Explorer plugin for Visual Studio Code. 
I have a folder with all my code in it, including source code for the project AND the test code. 
The Test Explorer doesn't find the tests, and i've set the:
    "dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath"
setting to the actual folder, but still nothing.

Any ideas on how to get the VSC's Core Test Explorer to actually find my tests? These are all *.cs files. thanks

Answer (score 6):

It is a problem with your name of the test csproj.

In **.NET Core Test Explorer** extension's details we can read:

> the glob pattern "+(testProjectOne|testProjectTwo)" or
>   "*/Tests.csproj" should add both of the test projects.

However, default templates name of csproj are different.

For instance - **dotnet new nunit** has a project name **projectName.TestProject.csproj**. So, it is not included in the glob pattern.

**Two solutions:**

1. Change project name to **projectName.Tests.csproj**
2. Change settings of .NET Core Test Explorer to

   "dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath": "*/*.TestProject.csproj"

Comment: It does work for Windows but I'm not seeing test cases under Linux with the same config. Any idea?

Comment: In my case (Mac) I had to add the new created Tests project to the main solution and build it. You can do that in VS Code by opening the Explorer side menu (left), then at the bottom expand the "Solution Exporer)", right-click on the solution and select "Add Existing Project"